# Probability that an exact allocation of balls into bins happens?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Say I have an infinite supply of bins, $1, 2 ,3 ...$, each having the same capacity for $c$ balls.

A process produces a random amount of $b$ balls, $min<=b<=max$ per iteration. All possible values of $b$ being equiprobable, each iteration independent.

As balls are received at each iteration, they are placed into the lowest numbered bin with remaining capacity, any excess over bin capacity going into the next highest numbered bin.

Sort of like batches of water filling one jug, which can overflow into a next jug, which itself can overflow into a subsequent jug, and so on.

I'd like to calculate the probability that over $i$ iterations of the process, there is at least one iteration where all bins with balls are each *exactly* at their common capacity $c$.

I honestly haven't a clue how to even begin here, apologies I can't show what I've attempted.

Edit: A simple example case.

Let $min, max, c, i$ = $1, 2, 3, 4$

We have then the following possible tuples of outcomes for the $i=4$ iterations:

> {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 2}, 
>     {1, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 2}, 
>     {2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2, 2}, 
>     {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}}

Accumulating each gives the sums for each case at each iteration (bold where the sum is exactly divisible by $c$):

> {{1, 2, ***3***, 4}, {1, 2, ***3***, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 4, ***6***}, {1, ***3***, 4, 
>     5}, {1, ***3***, 4, ***6***}, {1, ***3***, 5, ***6***}, {1, ***3***, 5, 7}, {2, ***3***, 4, 5}, {2, ***3***, 
>     4, ***6***}, {2, ***3***, 5, ***6***}, {2, ***3***, 5, 7}, {2, 4, 5, ***6***}, {2, 4, 5, 7}, {2, 
>     4, ***6***, 7}, {2, 4, ***6***, 8}}

Simply counting the possible outcomes that contain at least one element meeting the criteria, we see that the probability of at least one of the sums over 4 iterations with minimum 1 ball produced and maximum 2 balls produced per iteration, with bin capacity 3, being divisible exactly by the capacity is $7/8$.

I perhaps worded the "...haven't a clue..." above poorly, and meant "...haven't a clue *how to do this efficiently*...".

In this trivial case, a simple Markov chain with transition matrix:

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

suffices to get what I'm after for some arbitrary $i$ iterations.

However, for larger cases (I'd like to apply this for exact results for $min  \approx 10^3, max \approx 10^4, c \approx 10^4, i \approx 10^3$) the number of states/transitions becomes huge.

I'm fine with "there's probably not a more efficient way vs your Markov chain" if that's the determination of the experts here, but I never cease to be surprised by efficient methods for calculations that seem intractable at first sight that appear in answers here.

Hence the question.

Comment: I'm sorry: I didn't catch the probability part of the problem.  Is it that with each iteration $b$ is chosen randomly?  Are the $b$ choices independent from iteration to iteration?  With what probability law?  However chosen, aren't you asking if the sum of the $b$ values is exactly divisible by $c$, at least once?

Comment: @kimchilover - yes, i realized I'd not specified how $b$ is generated, edited after realization, then saw your query.

Comment: After a given iteration, all bins with balls will be at max capacity if and only if the total number of balls produced up to and including that iteration is a multiple of $c$.

Comment: Do you have specific values for min, max, c? Or at least a test case?

Comment: @quasi - that much is obvious and I know how to calculate that for a given iteration. What is not obvious to me is how to use that to get the overall probability for some given number of iterations.

Comment: @rasher: "I know how to calculate that for a given iteration" -- I'm not sure I understand your point. Can you show your work for whatever it is you're saying you know how to calculate?

Comment: @quasi - I mean I know how to calculate the probability that the sum of $n$ random integers over [min,max] is divisible by some integer $m$. I'm after the probability that for at least one case of the partial sums, a sum is divisible by some integer $m$...

Comment: @rasher: Have you worked out the answers for any test cases? If so, which case, and what were your results? If not, can you suggest a case for testing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63694/discussion-between-rasher-and-quasi).

Comment: Why not just give a test case? Edit it into your question. If you've worked it out already, show your work.

Comment: @quasi - I don't understand the aggression. As I said, I'm out for the moment, I will edit it in to the question when I'm back at a machine with a real keyboard - doing so on a mobile is a PITA.

Comment: It's not aggression. You are supposed to participate. No problem, it can wait until later. But testing is a natural starting point for exploring this problem, so my request for test data shouldn't be viewed as an attack.

Comment: Let $m,M$ be the min,max values for $b$. Let $p_i$ be the probability that for some $j$ with $1 \le j \le i$, after $j$ iterations, all bins with balls are at max capacity (i.e., they all contain exactly $c$ balls). If I understand your question correctly, for given values of $m,M,c,i$, you want to find $p_i$. Right? If so, by a test case, I just mean suggested values for $m,M,c,i$, so just $4$ numbers, nothing more.

Comment: @quasi - edited as promised.

Comment: Your edit makes the issues much clearer, both for me, and probably also for others. I don't know if I can help with the question, but at least now I understand it. Thanks for making the effort (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Edited 12 hours later, after OP revised question, and after I found confusing typos in my original answer.

So consider the random walk $S_i = B_1+ B_2+\dots+B_i \bmod c$, where the $B_i$ are chosen uniformly and independently from $\{m,m+1,\ldots,M\}$, and the killed random walk $S'_i$ obtained by removing mass when $S_i \equiv 0 \pmod c$, for $i>0$.
The probability you want, that $S_t$ hits $0 \bmod c$ before time $i$ is 1 minus the probability that $S'_i$ is alive at time $i$.  It is easy to see that the probability that $S'_i$ is alive decays to 0 exponentially quickly, but I don't have an  estimate of the rate in mind just now.

As you suspected, your combination of parameters is awkward.  I don't know how numerically stable the following procedure is, but it might give usable numerical approximations.  Let $\lambda=(\lambda_0,\ldots,\lambda_{c-1}) \in\mathbb C^c$ be the mod $c$ FFT of the uniform distribution on $\{m,m+1,\ldots,M\}$.  Initialize a complex vector $z=(z_0,\ldots z_{c-1})\in\mathbb C^c$ with all $1$s: $z\leftarrow(1,1,\dots,1)$.  Repeat the following process $i$ times:  first, update $z$ by multiplying coordinatewise by $\lambda$, and then, subtract from each entry in $z$ the average of all the entries in $z$ . (Simultaneously, not serially, of course.)  After $i$ steps of this, $z$ should be the FFT of the probability distribution of the killed process $S_i'$, and the probability it is alive should be $z_0$, and your desired probability should be $1-z_0$.  (The total cost here is about $O(c\log c + ic)$ which compares favorably to a direct matrix multiplication methods involving $i$ matvec operations which  would take $O(c^2)$ or $O(c\log c)$ apiece.)